# How to add a new User with Spring Security without restart spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

After finishing startup spring boot, Spring Security's configuration can not update . how to add new user or update user password or user role without restart spring boot? Because the page was redirected to the /login?error page, when I use new password to login.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    MemberMapper memberMapper;

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.addFilterBefore(new loginFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class).
                authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/register/**","/log/**").permitAll();



        http.formLogin().loginPage("/log/toLogin") 
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/log/login") 
                        .usernameParameter("memacc")
                        .passwordParameter("mempwd")
                        .failureHandler(new AppsAuthenticationFailureHandler());;





        http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");


    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        List<Members> allMembers = memberMapper.getAllMembers();

        for (Members members : allMembers){
            String[] roleList = members.getRoleList().split(",");
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
                .withUser(members.getMemacc()).password(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(members.getMempwd())).roles(roleList);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any specifiy needs of using inMemoryAuthentication()? Or is it okay to use another type of authentication?

Comment: InMemoryAuthentication is basically used to provide a static set of users (probably only for testing purposes).  You need to provide a proper signup flow if you need to provide dynamic user creation support

Comment: no, Just want to use simple way to handle dynamic user creation or update user detail

Comment: inMemoryAuthentication is for fixed user. could I use UserDetailsService dynamic  Authentication ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all,
I found the solution.

```
@EnableWebSecurity

public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     
        http.csrf().disable();
        
        http.addFilterBefore(new loginFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class).
                authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/register/**","/log/**").permitAll();

        
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/log/toLogin")
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/log/login") 
                        .usernameParameter("memacc")
                        .passwordParameter("mempwd");
        http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }
}
```

use the class implement UserDetailsService inteface. when user log in then authentate that user.

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    MemberMapper memberMapper;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Members member = memberMapper.getOneMemberByMemacc(username);
        if(member == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username + " not found");
        UserDetails userDetails = User.builder()
                .username(member.getMemacc())
                .password("{noop}" + member.getMempwd())
                .roles(member.getRoleList()).build();
        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do the login process, spring boots saves the user profile in memory.
If you add a new ROLE for a logged user for example and save in database, the user profile in memory didn't change and thats why you have to update this data.

You can make it with:

```
User user = userService.findById(idUser);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, user.getPassword(), user.getRoles()));
```

With this command, you update the user profile in spring-security memory.

Comment: thx. I use the method provided by you to solve new log in problem, but it can not handle problem when user change password then log in.

Comment: I am not understanding your problem. If you changed the password in database and change de user in Spring-security, your user is already updated and logged. You don't have to do nothing else

Comment: yes , that situation can work,but the user will not be authenticated by spring security when first log out and then log in.